# MongoDb v.1.8+: How to run Map-Reduce in temp collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

"*v1.8+: the output options have changed. Map-reduce no longer generates temporary collections...*". Does it mean I have to manually delete map-reduce produced collection, or there is still a way to say map-reduce: I need this output as an temporary intermediate storage only, remove it as soon as you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to either manually remove the named collection identified in the output option (once you're done with it), or use the `{ inline: 1 }` output option which returns the output from RAM (and live with that output option's limitations).